# SQLERVER CONVERT VARCHAR DATE TO DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have got dates as `varchar(50) 2006-07-13 00:00:00` and its giving me error when converting it to date using the formula below `cast(2006-07-13 00:00:00 as date)`.

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: sorry im not shouting

Comment: ...or, your finger is stuck on *shift*?

Comment: That can't be the error you're getting from `CAST(2006-07-13 00:00:00 AS DATE)`.  That would give you "Incorrect syntax near '00'" because you don't have the literal in quotes.

Comment: Also, when I run `select CAST('2006-07-13 00:00:00' AS DATE)`, I don't get an error.  So, I don't know what you're doing.  You need to give us the *actual* statement you're running that's producing that error.

Comment: try `SELECT cast('2006-07-13 00:00:00' as date)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using quotes:

```
select CAST('2006-07-13 00:00:00' AS DATE)
```

However, the `cast()` is generally redundant.  In most contexts where SQL Server expects a date, the string `'2006-07-13'` will be recognized as a date (there is one arcane internationalization setting where this doesn't work).